# Have perl direct file to Win 7 send to shortcut

Tags: windows, perl, shell

I have shortcut on shell:SendTo folder that I want to utilize. I am making an input processing script in Perl and i am not sure how to do this. Manually i would right click on the file and Sent To -> destination. I know Perl can do mouse clicks but i figured there is a more direct way of getting this happen. How do i go about this?

UPDATE

So the send to is a shortcut that points to a perl script that sends batch files to a HPC. Now I want to perform the sendto in perl. I am not so concerned with the destination as opposed to avoiding the right click. If I can code perl so it can activate this short cut by some command that is the same as right click and sending to a target I can greatly reduce the manual aspects of some input processing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To make sure I understand your question, are you asking for Perl code to send a file via email once the file is received/created?

Comment: I have a perl script that ships off batch files to be processed on a HPC. I send my batch files manually with a right click -> send to --> Target HPC. I want to do this from within Perl so I can automate it rather than right click everytime

Comment: You really should explain in more detail what you are trying to do. "Send To" can direct files to email, directories, network drives, other computers in your local net, shortcuts... Not to forget that is always appreciated if you post what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: @DeVadder I updated my thread post, I am not sure what else i can say in this regard though

Comment: So you have another script that is called SendTo. And you want to execute that script from within your current script. Basically Perl does things in a command line. So the question is, can you use your SendTo script from a command line? Maybe `C:\path\SendTo.pl file destination` or similar? If so, you can use that command from within your other perl script as `system "C:\path\SendTo.pl file destination"`.

Comment: @DeVadder but what about in a more general sense say i was not going to another executable? So your view point is rather than utilize the existing shortcut hard code the path. This would not work as I do not control the location and the shortcut is not maintained by me. It would be much better to pipe through the shortcut than the route directly to the file location.

Comment: Will this [help](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=263858)?

Comment: Windows shortcuts are usually _links_ to files, but can also be a link to an _action_ such as the _Send to_ shortcut. The SendTo menu on Win7 is located under the User's home under AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/SendTo. I believe the OP is asking how to get his Perl program to run when he uses the Mail Recipient link from the Context Menu (RightClick).

Comment: @DavidW. I think this may help but entirely sure. So does the link describe how to read a shortcut. Once I have read it I can then just run it like any other system call? Need a little guidance i am somewhat new to Perl.. Can you put as a solution so I can give you credit also...

Comment: There are several different kinds of _Shortcuts_ Windows has. When you create a _shortcut_, you create a `*.lnk` file. However, Windows can do a few other types of shortcuts. For example, the _Mail Recipient_ is a `MAPIMail` type. The _Desktop (create shortcut)_ is a `DeskLink` file. The whole thing is poorly documented. See http://superuser.com/questions/456399/what-different-types-of-shortcut-are-there for more information.

Comment: If you drag a Windows LNK shortcut to an executable program to this directory, and that program can take a command line file argument, you can select this from the Sendto folder, and it will act upon that file. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Perl and Batch scripts.

Comment: I have several perl scripts that use `*.lnk` shortcuts just like any other executable. But yeah, the problem is that the rightclick-menu SendTo entry can do a whole lot of different thinks that you would have to handle differently to each other in Perl. So unless you can find out what your specific SendTo action actually does (call some program, move the file, send it per mail, create a shortcut...) we can probably not help you.

Answer (score 0):

create a shortcut to your perl.exe in sendTo folder.
open the properties of that shortcut and add the path to your script as a parameter behind the exe

this should work

in the script you can get the filename with

```
my $filename = shift;
```